# Better way of displaying Error Message Layouts

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Fragment which can display multiple errors (No Internet, No elements found and a few others).

Now I have two ways of displaying the errors:

1. Making an extra layout in the same fragment and setting it's visibility to "gone" and changing TextView and the image according to the error.
2. Making different Fragments with error messages and launching those fragments accordingly.

I am confused which method is more faster and memory friendly.

Comment: see [this](https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/showing.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the 1st way, just a single layout and focus on custom error message.

Because creating multiple fragment is not a good practice because it will boilerplate code of initiating layout, `findViewById`,... and consume more memory.

Btw base on [this](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/errors.html#errors-app-errors) material design guidelines, you should use `Snackbar` for displaying error, so you don't have to create custom layout, just focus on the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to create your own layout for that purpose such as this [Layout](https://github.com/xiprox/ErrorView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/tr/xip/errorview/ErrorView.java).

Which will be simple to use and modified  on different error type e.g:

```
<....CustomLayout
        android:id="@+id/error_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:ev_imageSize="120dp"
        app:ev_retryColor="@color/apptheme_accent"
        app:ev_subtitle="Something went terribly wrong!" />
```

And in java:

```
customLayout.setImage(int res)
customLayout.setTitle(String)
customLayout.setSubtitle(String)
customLayout.setRetryText(String)
customLayout.setRetryListener(RetryListener)
```